# ComponentSpace.SAML2, .NET Core 2.2, IdentityServer4 2.3.2 - Strange behavior with AddSaml overload and SamlMiddleware

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4, saml-2.0

I'm doing a proof of concept for SP-initiated SSO using `IdentityServer4` as the IDP, with the `ComponentSpace.Saml2` library. I'm currently limited to `dotnet Core 2.2` and `IdentityServer4 2.3.2` as upgrading them is a significant undertaking and beyond the scope of this project.

So, my initial POC went well and worked as expected, loading the `PartnerServiceProvider` config directly from `appsettings.json`. Next we are trying to get multiple SP configs from the database in a fashion roughly like this:

```
var SSOConfigKeys = Configuration.GetSection("SAMLVendorConnections").Get<string[]>();
// we need to instantiate this so we can use the config in startup here
ISPInitiatedVendorSSOConfigSelector vendorSSOCfg = new SPInitiatedVendorSSOConfigSelector(deps);

Dictionary<string, SPInitiatedVendorSSOConfig> ssoCfgMap = new Dictionary<string, SPInitiatedVendorSSOConfig>();

SamlConfigurations samlCfg = Configuration.GetSection("SAML").Get<SamlConfigurations>();
samlCfg.Configurations.First().PartnerServiceProviderConfigurations = new List<PartnerServiceProviderConfiguration>();

foreach (var k in SSOConfigKeys)
{
    ssoCfgMap.Add(k, await vendorSSOCfg.Get(k));
    samlCfg.Configurations.First().PartnerServiceProviderConfigurations.Add(
        new PartnerServiceProviderConfiguration()
        {
            // set properties based on what we got from the db
        });
}

services.AddSaml((cfg) =>
{
    cfg = samlCfg;
})
```

But the problem stems from now using the `IServiceCollection.AddSaml(Action<SamlConfigurations>)` overload instead of the `IServiceCollection.AddSaml(IConfiguration)` overload used in the static config case.

1. Where it was working before, now I get a developer exception page telling me to use `IIdentityServerBuilder.AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()`, and not only that but even with that added in `ConfigureServices` the message persists until I remove/comment `app.UseIdentityServer()` in `Configure`
2. Once that is done, now I get an error saying `SamlMiddleware` is not registered, even though I call `IServiceCollection.AddSamlMiddleware()` in `ConfigureServices` and according to ComponentSpace that calls `IServiceCollection.AddTransient<SamlMiddleware>()` under the hood.

I've tried every `ComponentSpace.Saml2` version from `3.0.0` (minimum that has the middleware features I need) up to `4.0.0` (maximum that is compatible with Core 2.2) and the behavior is the same. I've been in touch with ComponentSpace as well and they are stumped too. Does anyone know what may be going on here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - it's that you have to encapsulate the config change in an `Action<SamlConfigurations>` and return the call to it in the lambda you pass to `AddSaml()`, and also set the `Configurations` property instead of the `SamlConfigurations` object itself, like so:

```
Dictionary<string, SPInitiatedVendorSSOConfig> ssoCfgMap = new Dictionary<string, SPInitiatedVendorSSOConfig>();

Action<SamlConfigurations> conifgureSaml = (config) => {
  var SSOConfigKeys = Configuration.GetSection("SAMLVendorConnections").Get<string[]>();

  ISPInitiatedVendorSSOConfigSelector vendorSSOCfg = new 
  SPInitiatedVendorSSOConfigSelector(deps);

  SamlConfigurations samlCfg = Configuration.GetSection("SAML").Get<SamlConfigurations>();
 
 
  samlCfg.Configurations.First()
    .PartnerServiceProviderConfigurations = new List<PartnerServiceProviderConfiguration>();

  foreach (var k in SSOConfigKeys)
  {
    ssoCfgMap.Add(k, await vendorSSOCfg.Get(k));
    samlCfg.Configurations.First().PartnerServiceProviderConfigurations.Add(
        new PartnerServiceProviderConfiguration()
        {
            // set properties based on what we got from the db
        });
  }

  config.configurations = SamlConfig.Configurations;
}

services.AddSaml((cfg) => configureSaml(cfg));
```

This fixes the issue with needing `AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()` and `UseIdentityServer()` as well, so everything works as I would expect.